# Put coloured text in a pandas data frame python

Tags: python, pandas

I have specific text highlighted with:

```
from termcolor import colored
text='left foot right foot left foot right. Feet in the day, feet at night.'
l1=['foot','feet']
result = " ".join(colored(t,'white','on_red') if t in l1 else t for t in text.lower().split())
print(result)
```

I want to put this text into a data frame.

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'text':[result]})
df['text'][0]
```

but ended up with :

```
'left \x1b[41m\x1b[37mfoot\x1b[0m right \x1b[41m\x1b[37mfoot\x1b[0m left \x1b[41m\x1b[37mfoot\x1b[0m right. \x1b[41m\x1b[37mfeet\x1b[0m in the day, \x1b[41m\x1b[37mfeet\x1b[0m at night.'
```

is there a way to put the highlighted text in a dataframe where the text is highlighted, and not with the extra code?

I would like to see in its place:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Updated to show what I want to see in the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but more of an explanation. Visual styling in pandas is implemented on a `DataFrame` level dependant on the data within.

In other words, you can style a specific cell with CSS attributes, either text color, background color, ..etc. But you can't embed a styled text within it.

As an example for whats feasible, check the following example:

```
text='left foot right foot left foot right. Feet in the day, feet at night.'
l1=['foot','feet']

def colorize(val):
    """
    return red color for specific words
    """
    color = 'red' if val in ['foot', 'feet'] else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' %color 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=text.lower().split(), columns=['words'])
df.style.applymap(colorize)
```

Output:
[image]